# Inconsistent implicit hash creation in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, syntax, hash

Ok, so I was comparing some stuff in my own DSL to Ruby. One construct they both support is this

```
x=["key" => "value"]
```

Knowing the difference between arrays and hashes, I would think this to be illegal, but the result in Ruby is

```
[{"key" => "value"}]
```

Why is this? And with this kinda syntax why can't you do

```
x=("key" => "value")
```

Why is an array a special case for implicitly created hashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another special case is in a function call, consider:

```
def f(x)
  puts "OK: #{x.inspect}"
end
f("foo" => "bar")
=> OK: {"foo"=>"bar"}
```

So in some contexts, Hashes can be built implicitly (by detecting the `=>` operator?).  I suppose the answer is just that this was Matz's least-surprising behavior.

Comment: This is the closest answer. It's just part of the syntax. Chatted some in #RubyOnRails to discover that it is part of the Ruby grammar.

Answer (score 2):

With this apparent inconsistency in implicit hash creation, ruby achieves consistency in this regard:

```
func(whatever...)
```

can always be substituted with:

```
args = [whatever...]
func(*args)
```

You can convert between argument lists and arrays, and therefore it is logical that they have the same syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the interpreter figures out that "key" => "value" is a hash, the same way it would figure out that 5 is a number when you put it into an array. 
So if you write:

```
x = [5]
```

The interpreter is not going to think that it is a string, and return:

```
x = ["5"]
```

It seems that ruby implicitly creates hashes in some instances.

Comment: yes, but `x=(5)` and `x=("5")` are all valid (the parentheses was just put in as possible disambiguation) so why not `x=("key" => "value")` Why can you put this in an array but not straight into a variable?

Comment: @Earlz - you can't put that straight into a variable as it isn't like a string or number in that way. It shows an association between 2 items in a hash. It seems that when you initialise it in an array, it converts it to a hash, but when you try to put it into a variable it doesn't