# How to create a YAML structure with an array of hashes from a ruby array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hashmap, yaml

My task is to express a YAML structure like the following from ruby data structures:

```
- a
- b
- a
- include:
    name: test 
- include:
    name: test2
```

I tried the following:

```
require "json"
#=> true
require "yaml"
#=> true
array = ["a","b","a","include" => {"name"=>"test"}]
#=> ["a", "b", "a", {"include"=>{"name"=>"test"}}]
puts JSON.parse(array.to_json).to_yaml
#---
#- a
#- b
#- a
#- include:
#    name: test
#=> nil
```

So this looks like I'm on the right track. But when I simply add another hash entry into the array I get the following:

```
array = ["a","b","a","include" => {"name"=>"test"}, "include" => {"name"=>"test2"}]
#(irb):23: warning: duplicated key at line 23 ignored: "include"
#=> ["a", "b", "a", {"include"=>{"name"=>"test2"}}]
puts JSON.parse(array.to_json).to_yaml
#---
#- a
#- b
#- a
#- include:
#    name: test2
#=> nil
```

This confuses me a lot. Shouldn't the entries of an array be independent of each other? Why does Ruby merge the last two entries together to one hash? And what do I have to do to create the given YAML structure with ruby data structures, if that is possible at all (I'm sorry if that is a stupid question, but I'm a Ruby beginner)?

Comment: you have _duplicate_ key, which is not allowed.. You need to have uniq names .. You have `include` _twice_.

Comment: I see that ruby thinks I have duplicate keys. But I think it is wrong. The two "include"'s are just two entries in an array, the same as the two "a"'s. But ruby is treating them as if they belong to one hash. That is really confusing.

Comment: Ohh! okay, I then probably misunderstood. :)

Comment: Why do people downvote such a question?

Comment: I don't know.. I didn't.. But not questions, sometime good answers also attacked by some _non sense_ people out there. Don't care them Man!

Comment: @asmaier I've added the missing return values, take a look at your array. Maybe you have been downvoted because the bug is so obvious.

Comment: If this is obvious, then this question shouldn't have got any upvotes, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838581/inconsistent-implicit-hash-creation-in-ruby.

Comment: I rephrased the question and hope it is now more suitable for this site.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting extra braces around your hashes - or else Ruby thinks it's just one hash at the end of the array.

```
["a", "b", "a", {"include" => {"name"=>"test"}}, {"include" => {"name"=>"test2"}}].to_yaml
```